# Cross-browser loading indication in Javascript

Tags: javascript, user-interface, cross-browser, pushstate

I'm working on an application that uses pushState *heavily*. Some page loads are quick, some require many calls back to our API. We've been able to fake some of the browser loading stuff view CSS:

```
body.loading { cursor: progress; }
```

This works *ok* in windows browsers (it's not standard on Mac), but I'd like some way to, for each browser, put the browser in the same state it's in when you click a link and do a real page load:

1. The loading indiciator on the top spins
2. In windows, the progress indicator cursor shows (this doesn't happen in Safari on mac)

Is there a browser facility to do this, or do we just have to display some dweeby ajax loading indicator?

Comment: I don't think I would call an AJAX loading indicator *dweeby*. I think that's probably the most effective way to do it. Example: Gmail

Comment: Maybe. I'd just like to stay away from WEB2.0!!!11 stuff if possible. Our goal is to match our experience to the native browser experience as closely as possible.